# Simplifying entry of classpath for java programs created in eclipse, when run from cli?

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, classpath, command-line-interface

I use eclipse as my IDE to save projects onto a samba network drive that I have mapped on my ubuntu home server. I have Eclipse configured to save the jar libraries that I'm using into the /lib folder.

The problem is that when I try to run my java programs from the command line on the server, I always have to type

```
java -cp .:../lib/* javaclassname
```

This gets a bit tiresome, especially considering tab-completion won't work with the colon that must be included in the classpath. Is there any way to set things up so I don't have to manually specify the classpath every time?

Comment: Look into how you can make your programs runnable by having a Class-Path entry in your MANIFEST.MF

Comment: make an alias, or a script?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I haven't been making jars but I will look into it if that will make things easier - is that what ant does?

Comment: @vikingsteve Yes, I could make a script or alias but usually these are small test programs and not really worth the effort of custom scripts. I'd still like to find a way to set up defaults in eclipse to automate things.

Comment: Have you considered using a build tool like Ant? Or dependency manager like Maven? Those tools eliminate these sorts of repetitive manual tasks.

Comment: @Perception Thanks, I am considering it now. Maven sounds like it might be what I'm looking for. More tools to learn...

Comment: Maven is great for building jars / programs / artifacts, but perhaps not so suited to running them (?). @OP - is it feasible to set up the run targets in your IDE and run them from there?

Comment: @vikingsteve - you can run programs with Maven just fine, with the `mvn exec:java` command. Of course, its not the best options when talking about running the final deployable, but it sounds like the OP is doing this more as part of his development cycle.

Comment: No worries, thanks for that tip @Perception. If its part of the dev cycle, i still would recommend run targets in the IDE.

Comment: @vikingsteve the problem is that I am developing on my main Windows 7 machine, but trying to run the program on my ubuntu server (I'm trying to learn client/server stuff atm). The windows machine is fine for testing locally.

Comment: Oh, ok. I guess you could create a jar-with-dependencies, and run that on your ubuntu machine? @see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by making a shell script called `run.sh` and putting it in the project's root folder.

run.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

LIBS=$(grep '<classpathentry kind="lib" path="' .classpath | sed 's/.*\<classpathentry kind="lib" path="//' | sed 's/\"[^\"]*$//' | tr '\n' ':')

java -cp "bin:$LIBS" $1
```

You make it executable by running `chmod u+x run.sh`, then run it with `./run.sh packagename.classname`

It reads the `.classpath` file in the root folder and adds every entry to the colon-separated list on the commandline.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is to let Eclipse build the JAR for you.  Right-click on your project, then select Export > Runnable JAR file.  The dialog will give you a few options.  Select 'Copy required libraries...'.  The output will be your main application JAR file, plus a lib folder with your dependencies.  In this case, the JAR file manifest will specify the class path, which points to all your dependencies.  Running it at the command line then would be as simple as "java -jar myJar.jar".

If you want to automate things, I would start with Ant.  I think it will be less of a learning curve than Maven.  In this case, check out the [`jar` Ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html).

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate Maven a bit more though, it sounds tempting with the dependency management included as well, and seems like it can do everything that ant does.